# Change ajaxForm options after it was called

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form and [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is used with it.

```
<form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
         alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Is it possible to add `beforeSubmit` handler **after** `ajaxForm` was already called to perform some validation? I'm asking this because `ajaxForm` is called in external code which I can't modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It is possible to get access to the options through submit event of the form:

```
$._data($('#myForm')[0], 'events')['submit'][0].data.beforeSubmit
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's impossible for now. But if you can get `options` variable passed to former call to `ajaxForm()` you can extend it with `beforeSubmit`.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't